# object crashing say it is NULL

Tags: c#, data-structures

I've created a class

```
public partial class Subrank
{
    private System.DateTime startDateField;

    public System.DateTime StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.startDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.startDateField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

im then trying to create an array of this...

```
Subrank[] pastSubRank = new Subrank[1];
pastSubRank[0].StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-22");
```

but `pastSubRank[0]` is crashing saying it is NULL....why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes cause you haven't instantiated the class `Subrank` before accessing it's property.

```
Subrank[] pastSubRank = new Subrank[1];
pastSubRank[0] = new Subrank();
pastSubRank[0].StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-22");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: You can also write 'Enumerable.Repeat(new Subrank(), 1).ToArray()' to initialize an array of objects.

Comment: @John, then consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @Rahul Accepted. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an object to put in the array before accessing property

```
        Subrank[] pastSubRank = new Subrank[1];
        pastSubRank[0] = new Subrank();
        pastSubRank[0].StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-22");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Subrank[] pastSubRank = new Subrank[]
{
    new Subrank() { StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-22") }
};
```